# Ajax table action and process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to learn Ajax better, and I'm developing an application in CodeIgniter.

The following code is working, there are no errors. But for every function and call I think I'm repeating callbacks too often.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        show_costumer();

        function show_costumer(){
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'ajax',
                url   : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/costumer_data",
                async : true,
                dataType : 'JSON',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="'+data[i].id_anagrafica+'" /></td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].nome+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].cognome+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].telefono+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].cf+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].data_nascita+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].comune+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].tipo_attivita+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].note_anagrafica+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].note_tipo_attivita+'</td>'+
                                '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-id_anagrafica="'+data[i].id_anagrafica+'" data-nome="'+data[i].nome+'" data-cognome="'+data[i].cognome+'" data-telefono="'+data[i].telefono+'" data-email="'+data[i].email+'" data-cf="'+data[i].cf+'" data-nascita="'+data[i].data_nascita+'" data-comune="'+data[i].comune+'"data-tipo_attivita="'+data[i].tipo_attivita+'" data-note_anagrafica="'+data[i].note_anagrafica+'" data-note_tipo_attivita="'+data[i].note_tipo_attivita+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-id_anagrafica="'+data[i].id_anagrafica+'">Delete</a>'+
                                '</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#show_costumer').html(html);
                }

            });

        }

        $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
          var search = $(this).val();
          if( search != "" ){
            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/search",
              data:'search='+$('#search_text').val(),
              dataType: "JSON",
              cache: false,
              success:function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                  html += '<tr>'+
                  '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="'+data[i].id_anagrafica+'" /></td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].nome+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].cognome+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].telefono+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].cf+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].data_nascita+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].comune+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].tipo_attivita+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].note_anagrafica+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].note_tipo_attivita+'</td>'+
                  '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                  '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-id_anagrafica="'+data[i].id_anagrafica+'" data-nome="'+data[i].nome+'" data-cognome="'+data[i].cognome+'" data-telefono="'+data[i].telefono+'" data-email="'+data[i].email+'" data-cf="'+data[i].cf+'" data-nascita="'+data[i].data_nascita+'" data-comune="'+data[i].comune+'"data-tipo_attivita="'+data[i].tipo_attivita+'" data-note_anagrafica="'+data[i].note_anagrafica+'" data-note_tipo_attivita="'+data[i].note_tipo_attivita+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                  '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-id_anagrafica="'+data[i].id_anagrafica+'">Delete</a>'+
                  '</td>'+
                  '</tr>';
                }
                $('#show_costumer').html(html);
              },
              error: function(data){
                return false;
              }
            });
          }
          else{
            show_costumer();
          }
        });

        //Save product
        $('#btn_save').on('click',function(){
            var id_anagrafica = $('#id_anagrafica').val();
            var nome = $('#nome').val();
            var cognome = $('#cognome').val();
            var telefono = $('#telefono').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var cf = $('#cf').val();
            var data_nascita = $('#data_nascita').val();
            var comune = $('#comune').val();
            var tipo_attivita = $('#tipo_attivita').val();
            var note_anagrafica = $('#note_anagrafica').val();
            var note_tipo_attivita = $('#note_tipo_attivita').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/save",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {id_anagrafica:id_anagrafica, nome:nome , cognome:cognome, telefono:telefono, email:email, cf:cf, data_nascita:data_nascita, comune:comune, tipo_attivita:tipo_attivita, note_anagrafica:note_anagrafica, note_tipo_attivita:note_tipo_attivita},
                success: function(data){
                    $('[name="id_anagrafica"]').val("");
                    $('[name="nome"]').val("");
                    $('[name="cognome"]').val("");
                    $('[name="telefono"]').val("");
                    $('[name="email"]').val("");
                    $('[name="cf"]').val("");
                    $('[name="data_nascita"]').val("");
                    $('[name="comune"]').val("");
                    $('[name="tipo_attivita"]').val("");
                    $('[name="note_anagrafica"]').val("");
                    $('[name="note_tipo_attivita"]').val("");
                    $('#addcostumer').modal('close');
                    show_costumer();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        //get data for update record
        $('#show_costumer').on('click','.item_edit',function(){
            var id_anagrafica = $(this).data('id_anagrafica');
            var nome = $(this).data('nome');
            var cognome = $(this).data('cognome');
            var telefono = $(this).data('telefono');
            var email = $(this).data('email');
            var cf = $(this).data('cf');
            var data_nascita = $(this).data('data_nascita');
            var comune = $(this).data('comune');
            var tipo_attivita = $(this).data('tipo_attivita');
            var note_anagrafica = $(this).data('note_anagrafica');
            var note_tipo_attivita = $(this).data('note_tipo_attivita');

            $('#Modal_Edit').modal('open');
            $('[name="id_anagrafica_edit"]').val(id_anagrafica);
            $('[name="nome_edit"]').val(nome);
            $('[name="cognome_edit"]').val(cognome);
            $('[name="telefono_edit"]').val(telefono);
            $('[name="email_edit"]').val(email);
            $('[name="cf_edit"]').val(cf);
            $('[name="data_nascita"]').val(data_nascita);
            $('[name="comune_edit"]').val(comune);
            $('[name="tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(tipo_attivita);
            $('[name="note_anagrafica_edit"]').val(note_anagrafica);
            $('[name="note_tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(note_tipo_attivita);
        });

        //update record to database
         $('#btn_update').on('click',function(){
           var id_anagrafica = $('#id_anagrafica_edit').val();
           var nome = $('#nome_edit').val();
           var cognome = $('#cognome_edit').val();
           var telefono = $('#telefono_edit').val();
           var email = $('#email_edit').val();
           var cf = $('#cf_edit').val();
           var data_nascita = $('#data_nascita_edit').val();
           var comune = $('#comune_edit').val();
           var tipo_attivita = $('#tipo_attivita_edit').val();
           var note_anagrafica = $('#note_anagrafica_edit').val();
           var note_tipo_attivita = $('#note_tipo_attivita_edit').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php base_url( 'admin/costumer/update' ) ?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {id_anagrafica:id_anagrafica, nome:nome , cognome:cognome, telefono:telefono, email:email, cf:cf, data_nascita:data_nascita, comune:comune, tipo_attivita:tipo_attivita, note_anagrafica:note_anagrafica, note_tipo_attivita:note_tipo_attivita},
                success: function(data){
                    $('[name="id_anagrafica_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="nome_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="cognome_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="telefono_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="email_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="cf_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="data_nascita_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="comune_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="tipo_attivita_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="note_anagrafica_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="note_tipo_attivita_edit"]').val("");
                    $('#Modal_Edit').modal('close');
                    show_costumer();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        //get data for delete record
        $('#show_costumer').on('click','.item_delete',function(){
            var id_anagrafica = $(this).data('id_anagrafica');

            $('#Modal_Delete').modal('open');
            $('[name="id_anagrafica_delete"]').val(id_anagrafica);
        });

        //delete record to database
          $('#btn_delete').on('click',function(){
             var id_anagrafica =$('#id_anagrafica_delete').val();
             $.ajax({
                 type : "POST",
                 url  : "<?php base_url('admin/costumer/delete') ?>",
                 dataType : "JSON",
                 data : {id_anagrafica:id_anagrafica},
                 success: function(data){
                     $('[name="id_anagrafica_delete"]').val("");
                     $('#Modal_Delete').modal('close');
                     show_costumer();
                 }
             });
             return false;
         });

        //delete all record to database
          $('#delete_all_costumers').on('click',function()
              {
                  if(this.checked)
                      {
                          $('.checkbox').each(function()
                              {
                                  this.checked = true;
                              }
                          );
                     }
                else
                    {

                      $('.checkbox').each(function()
                          {
                             this.checked = false;
                        }
                     );
                 }
             });

             $('.delete_all_customers').on('click', function(e) {

                 var allVals = [];
                 $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                     allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
                 });

                 if(allVals.length <=0)
                 {
                     alert("Please select row.");
                 }  else {

                     var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?");
                     if(check == true){

                         var join_selected_values = allVals.join(",");

                         $.ajax({
                             url: "<?php base_url( 'admin/costumer/delete_all' ) ?>
                             ",
                             type: 'POST',
                             data: 'id_anagrafica='+join_selected_values,
                             success: function (data) {
                               console.log(data);
                               $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                                   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                               });
                               alert("Item Deleted successfully.");
                             },
                             error: function (data) {
                                 alert(data.responseText);
                             }
                         });

                       $.each(allVals, function( index, value ) {
                           $('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + value + "']").remove();
                       });
                     }
                 }
             });

             $('.pagination').on('click','a',function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var page_number = $(this).attr('data-ci-pagination-page');
               loadPagination(page_number);
             });

             loadPagination(0);

             // Load pagination
             function loadPagination(page_number){
               $.ajax({
                 url: '<?=base_url()?>admin/costumer/load_record/'+page_number,
                 type: 'get',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(response){
                    $('.pagination').html(response.pagination);
                    createTable(response.result,response.row);
                 }
               });
             }

     // Create table list
     function createTable(result,sno){
       sno = Number(sno);
       $('#table tbody').empty();
       for(index in result){
          var id_anagrafica = result[index].id_anagrafica;
          var nome = result[index].nome;
          var cognome = result[index].cognome;
          var telefono = result[index].telefono;
          var email = result[index].email;
          var cf = result[index].cf;
          var data_nascita = result[index].data_nascita;
          var comune = result[index].comune;
          var tipo_attivita = result[index].tipo_attivita;
          var note_anagrafica = result[index].note_anagrafica;
          var note_tipo_attivita = result[index].note_tipo_attivita;
          // content = content.substr(0, 60) + " ...";
          // var link = result[index].link;
          sno+=1;

          var tr = "<tr>";
          tr += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-id="+ id_anagrafica +" /></td>";
          tr += "<td><div class='row_data' edit_type='click' col_name='fname'>"+ nome +"</div></td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ cognome +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ telefono +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ email +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ cf +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ data_nascita +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ comune +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ tipo_attivita +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ note_anagrafica +"</td>";
          tr += "<td>"+ note_tipo_attivita +"</td>";
          tr += '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
              '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-id_anagrafica="'+ id_anagrafica +'" data-nome="'+nome+'" data-cognome="'+cognome+'" data-telefono="'+telefono+'" data-email="'+email+'" data-cf="'+cf+'" data-nascita="'+data_nascita+'" data-comune="'+comune+'"data-tipo_attivita="'+tipo_attivita+'" data-note_anagrafica="'+note_anagrafica+'" data-note_tipo_attivita="'+note_tipo_attivita+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
              '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-id_anagrafica="'+id_anagrafica+'">Delete</a>'+
          '</td>';
          tr += "</tr>";
          $('#table tbody').append(tr);

        }
      }


      //--->make div editable > start
      $(document).on('click', '.row_data', function(event)
      {
      event.preventDefault();

      //make div editable
      $(this).closest('div').attr('contenteditable', 'true');

      $(this).focus();
      })
      //--->make div editable > end

});

</script>
```

Is this a good approach? What if I need to change or add a function? Do I need to edit every single function or is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: Did you test whether it works like you want it to? How?

Comment: Yes, I'm developing an application in codeigniter and every single line of code works as aspectly, but I think that there are a lot of redundant call ora ther is some way to write it in a more functional way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back and forget about what your code does; what does it *look like*? Find the text that's duplicated, then try sticking those in functions. If this code uses variables, make these arguments for your functions. If a few snippets of code are 90% similar, move one copy to a new function, then add an if-statement in this new function to support the other versions.

Here's some snippets things that could be made into functions:

```js
html += '<tr>' +
  '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="' + data[i].id_anagrafica + '" /></td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].nome + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].cognome + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].telefono + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].email + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].cf + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].data_nascita + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].comune + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].tipo_attivita + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].note_anagrafica + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + data[i].note_tipo_attivita + '</td>' +
  '<td style="text-align:right;">' +
  '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-id_anagrafica="' + data[i].id_anagrafica + '" data-nome="' + data[i].nome + '" data-cognome="' + data[i].cognome + '" data-telefono="' + data[i].telefono + '" data-email="' + data[i].email + '" data-cf="' + data[i].cf + '" data-nascita="' + data[i].data_nascita + '" data-comune="' + data[i].comune + '"data-tipo_attivita="' + data[i].tipo_attivita + '" data-note_anagrafica="' + data[i].note_anagrafica + '" data-note_tipo_attivita="' + data[i].note_tipo_attivita + '">Edit</a>' + ' ' +
  '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-id_anagrafica="' + data[i].id_anagrafica + '">Delete</a>' +
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>';

// ... could be ...
function row(data) {
  return '<tr>' +
    '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="' + data.id_anagrafica + '" /></td>' +
    '<td>' + data.nome + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.cognome + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.telefono + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.email + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.cf + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.data_nascita + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.comune + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.tipo_attivita + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.note_anagrafica + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.note_tipo_attivita + '</td>' +
    '<td style="text-align:right;">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-id_anagrafica="' + data.id_anagrafica + '" data-nome="' + data.nome + '" data-cognome="' + data.cognome + '" data-telefono="' + data.telefono + '" data-email="' + data.email + '" data-cf="' + data.cf + '" data-nascita="' + data.data_nascita + '" data-comune="' + data.comune + '"data-tipo_attivita="' + data.tipo_attivita + '" data-note_anagrafica="' + data.note_anagrafica + '" data-note_tipo_attivita="' + data.note_tipo_attivita + '">Edit</a>' + ' ' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-id_anagrafica="' + data.id_anagrafica + '">Delete</a>' +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
}
html += row(data[i]);


// This:
var id_anagrafica = $(this).data('id_anagrafica');
var nome = $(this).data('nome');
var cognome = $(this).data('cognome');
var telefono = $(this).data('telefono');
var email = $(this).data('email');
var cf = $(this).data('cf');
var data_nascita = $(this).data('data_nascita');
var comune = $(this).data('comune');
var tipo_attivita = $(this).data('tipo_attivita');
var note_anagrafica = $(this).data('note_anagrafica');
var note_tipo_attivita = $(this).data('note_tipo_attivita');

$('#Modal_Edit').modal('open');
$('[name="id_anagrafica_edit"]').val(id_anagrafica);
$('[name="nome_edit"]').val(nome);
$('[name="cognome_edit"]').val(cognome);
$('[name="telefono_edit"]').val(telefono);
$('[name="email_edit"]').val(email);
$('[name="cf_edit"]').val(cf);
$('[name="data_nascita"]').val(data_nascita);
$('[name="comune_edit"]').val(comune);
$('[name="tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(tipo_attivita);
$('[name="note_anagrafica_edit"]').val(note_anagrafica);
$('[name="note_tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(note_tipo_attivita);
});

// ... could be
function update(data) {
  $('[name="id_anagrafica_edit"]').val(data.id_anagrafica);
  $('[name="nome_edit"]').val(data.nome);
  $('[name="cognome_edit"]').val(data.cognome);
  $('[name="telefono_edit"]').val(data.telefono);
  $('[name="email_edit"]').val(data.email);
  $('[name="cf_edit"]').val(data.cf);
  $('[name="data_nascita"]').val(data.data_nascita);
  $('[name="comune_edit"]').val(data.comune);
  $('[name="tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(data.tipo_attivita);
  $('[name="note_anagrafica_edit"]').val(data.note_anagrafica);
  $('[name="note_tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(data.note_tipo_attivita);
}
$('#Modal_Edit').modal('open');
update($(this).data()); // similarly: update({}) to clear stuff


// This:
var id_anagrafica = $('#id_anagrafica_edit').val();
var nome = $('#nome_edit').val();
var cognome = $('#cognome_edit').val();
var telefono = $('#telefono_edit').val();
var email = $('#email_edit').val();
var cf = $('#cf_edit').val();
var data_nascita = $('#data_nascita_edit').val();
var comune = $('#comune_edit').val();
var tipo_attivita = $('#tipo_attivita_edit').val();
var note_anagrafica = $('#note_anagrafica_edit').val();
var note_tipo_attivita = $('#note_tipo_attivita_edit').val();

// ... could be:
function read() {
  return {
    id_anagrafica: $('#id_anagrafica_edit').val(),
    nome: $('#nome_edit').val(),
    cognome: $('#cognome_edit').val(),
    telefono: $('#telefono_edit').val(),
    email: $('#email_edit').val(),
    cf: $('#cf_edit').val(),
    data_nascita: $('#data_nascita_edit').val(),
    comune: $('#comune_edit').val(),
    tipo_attivita: $('#tipo_attivita_edit').val(),
    note_anagrafica: $('#note_anagrafica_edit').val(),
    note_tipo_attivita: $('#note_tipo_attivita_edit').val(),
  }
}
$.ajax({ ...snip...,
  data: read()
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've learned something new. My goals, perhaps, is to create a unique function  that control all td of table like:

`$(this).find('td').each (function() {
  // do your cool stuff
});`